# Python: Install a module out of source code

Tags: python, module, installation

certainly you all know the answer and it's easy going, but I'm new to python :)

I found a piece of code in the internet reading the stock price from yahoo finance

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
#  Copyright (c) 2007-2008, Corey Goldberg (corey@goldb.org)
#
#  license: GNU LGPL
#
#  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
#  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
#  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.


import urllib


"""
This is the "ystockquote" module.

This module provides a Python API for retrieving stock data from Yahoo Finance.

sample usage:
>>> import ystockquote
>>> print ystockquote.get_price('GOOG')
529.46
"""


def __request(symbol, stat):
    url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%s&f=%s' % (symbol, stat)
    return urllib.urlopen(url).read().strip().strip('"')


def get_all(symbol):
    """
    Get all available quote data for the given ticker symbol.

    Returns a dictionary.
    """
    values = __request(symbol, 'l1c1va2xj1b4j4dyekjm3m4rr5p5p6s7').split(',')
    data = {}
    data['price'] = values[0]
    data['change'] = values[1]
    data['volume'] = values[2]
    data['avg_daily_volume'] = values[3]
    data['stock_exchange'] = values[4]
    data['market_cap'] = values[5]
    data['book_value'] = values[6]
    data['ebitda'] = values[7]
    data['dividend_per_share'] = values[8]
    data['dividend_yield'] = values[9]
    data['earnings_per_share'] = values[10]
    data['52_week_high'] = values[11]
    data['52_week_low'] = values[12]
    data['50day_moving_avg'] = values[13]
    data['200day_moving_avg'] = values[14]
    data['price_earnings_ratio'] = values[15]
    data['price_earnings_growth_ratio'] = values[16]
    data['price_sales_ratio'] = values[17]
    data['price_book_ratio'] = values[18]
    data['short_ratio'] = values[19]
    return data


def get_price(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'l1')


def get_change(symbol):
    return __request(symbol, 'c1')


def get_volume(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'v')


def get_avg_daily_volume(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'a2')


def get_stock_exchange(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'x')


def get_market_cap(symbol):
    return __request(symbol, 'j1')


def get_book_value(symbol):
    return __request(symbol, 'b4')


def get_ebitda(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'j4')


def get_dividend_per_share(symbol):
    return __request(symbol, 'd')


def get_dividend_yield(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'y')


def get_earnings_per_share(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'e')


def get_52_week_high(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'k')


def get_52_week_low(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'j')


def get_50day_moving_avg(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'm3')


def get_200day_moving_avg(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'm4')


def get_price_earnings_ratio(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'r')


def get_price_earnings_growth_ratio(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'r5')


def get_price_sales_ratio(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'p5')


def get_price_book_ratio(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 'p6')


def get_short_ratio(symbol): 
    return __request(symbol, 's7')


def get_historical_prices(symbol, start_date, end_date):
    """
    Get historical prices for the given ticker symbol.
    Date format is 'YYYYMMDD'

    Returns a nested list.
    """
    url = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s&' % symbol + \
          'd=%s&' % str(int(end_date[4:6]) - 1) + \
          'e=%s&' % str(int(end_date[6:8])) + \
          'f=%s&' % str(int(end_date[0:4])) + \
          'g=d&' + \
          'a=%s&' % str(int(start_date[4:6]) - 1) + \
          'b=%s&' % str(int(start_date[6:8])) + \
          'c=%s&' % str(int(start_date[0:4])) + \
          'ignore=.csv'
    days = urllib.urlopen(url).readlines()
    data = [day[:-2].split(',') for day in days]
    return data
```

How do I install this module to use the commands? I'm using Windows 7 and Python 3.xx.

Thanks a lot!

Kurt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simply place it in the same directory as your script and you will be able to import it.

If you want to "install" it, you can place it as `C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\ystockquote.py`. You should then be able to import it with `import ystockquote`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is actually for python 2.x, and since python 3 is not backward compatible you won't be able to compile it using python 3.
My suggestion is for you to take a look at this [code](http://ashkax.posterous.com/python3-yahoo-finance-class-v1-0). That one is written for python 3, and you can use it using win7 and python 3.
Just create a file like test.py, put both files in the same directory, and write a code like:

```
from Ystock import  *
print (Ystock("GOOG").get_all())
print(Ystock("IBM+GOOG").get_stock_exchange());
print(Ystock("IBM+GOOG").get_dividend_per_share());
```

source:  http://ashkax.posterous.com/python3-yahoo-finance-class-v1-0