# python module from source code - naming

Tags: python, module, installation

I am a python *module-making* novice.  Following the spirit of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664075/python-install-a-module-out-of-source-code), I installed [Rx](http://rx.codesimply.com/) to validate some data from YAML files.  Wanting to keep the whole party together, I simply put the whole git tree under `site-packages`.  This provided me a (very simplified) tree to the python implementation of `site-packages/Rx/python/Rx.py`.

Since this cannot be directly imported, I added `__init__.py` to `site-packages/Rx`, with a single line:

```
from Rx.python.Rx import *
```

Since it **still** cannot be directly imported, I added `__init__.py` to `site-packages/Rx/python`, with a single line:

```
from Rx import *
```

Now, I can successfully import.  This is great, but I don't care for the following

```
>>> import Rx
>>> a = Rx.Factory()
>>> a
<Rx.python.Rx.Factory object at 0x00C0CCF0>
```

I would just like the objects to be referenced by the package name `Rx`, e.g., `<Rx.Factory object at 0x00C0CCF0>`.

How is this correctly done?  Thanks!

**EDIT**, for anyone who might come across the same problem:

I emptied out `site-packages/Rx/python/__init__.py`, and changed `site-packages/Rx/__init__.py`, as follows:

```
import os
__path__.append( os.path.join(__path__[0], 'python') )
from Rx import *
```

This isn't exactly what I wanted, but at least now the objects are `Rx.Rx.Factory`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no code in the top level Rx/python directories you canjust remove them and put the Rx.py file into site-packages.

If you want to keep the whole git tree together you can symlink the Rx file from somewhere into site-packages, but it would be better to modify your PYTHONPATH variable to include the directory that conains Rx.py.

The Python document on [Modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) is very comprehensive. Definitely check out the section on [the module search path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Comment: Although it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it happened to lead me there, so I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern is to setup your project like this:

```
ProjectName/
|-- bin/
|   `-- myscript
|-- package_name/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- rx.py
`-- setup.py
```

Your setup script then looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='ProjectName',
      version='1.0',
      description='My project description',
      author='Me',
      author_email='Me@localhost',
      url='http://localhost/',
      packages=['package_name'],
     )
```

When you run:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Distutils will copy your package directory into site-packages.

With the above structure your imports would look like:

```
from package_name import Rx
print Rx.Factory
```

What it sounds like you want is:

```
import package_name
print package_name.Factory
```

To do that you'll want to add the following to your **init**.py:

```
from rx import Factory
```

For development you could symbolically link your package directory into site-packages but there are quite a few other ways to add development code to your PYTHONPATH without symbolic links.

The simplest way to do it is to simply change directory to your project directory (cd ProjectName based on the above example) and then just execute your script from there.

If you don't like that you could append your development package to your PYTHONPATH by doing something like:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/me/ProjectName
```

Yet another way to do it is to use a *.pth file to add your development package to the site-packages and have it still live in your home directory.  To do this you'll just create a simple file called something like myproject.pth which will include:

```
# pth file for Rx development
/home/me/ProjectName
```

The nice thing about pth files is that you can move your code around, rename the package, add a second package, etc and it will still be importable without monkeying with your symlinks.

Of course there are other options like manipulation of sys.path in your user startup files, tools like virtualenv, buildout, etc.